# Alterar o docker-compose reflete no container atual?

Tags: docker

Caso eu altere a porta exposta no meu `docker-compose`, ao rodar `docker-compose up -d` essa alteração irá refletir no container atual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ideia de container no Docker é justamente ele ser efêmero, ou seja ele pode morrer a qualquer momento. Seguindo essa ideia, ao meu ver, não seria adequado alterar a porta de um container já existe, mas sim criar um novo container e expor a porta desejada.

No seu caso, você pode alterar o arquivo ***yaml*** que está sendo lido pelo **docker-compose** e alterar aporta, posteriormente a isso poderia fazer algo como `docker-compose up -d`, isso vai gerar um novo container com as alterações especificadas no arquivo de configuração.

*Complementando: dentro do seu arquivo de configuração (definição) do docker-compose você pode especificar um Dockerfile e definir tudo que sua imagem vai precisar, assim poderá destruir e subir o container sempre que precisar sem a necessidade de ficar reinstalando as coisas manualmente.*

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação. Isso já resolve meu problema.